# Why am I able to fork other answers' snippets?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098848/1234256) uses a snippet. Other answers on the same question do, as well. Every snippet -- in question or answer -- shows <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> and <kbd>Copy snippet to answer</kbd>.

Isn't it a bad idea to allow users to fork other users' answers? It encourages plagiarism and low-quality, duplicate answers.

Comment: It's just a glorified copy; any plagiarist can always hit 'edit' then copy and paste manually. Inconveniencing non-infringing users because *some* people cannot be bothered to write something original is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Not sure why there are already a few downvotes but not a single comment explaining the disagreement. Your statements are true and I agree with them - I am curious to hear what others think...

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?  Do you have examples of people abusing the feature to plagiarize content?

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it a bad idea to allow users to fork other users' answers? It encourages plagiarism and low-quality, duplicate answers.

It encourages building on other people's answers, which is quite appropriate on SO. If a user sees an answer and finds it works but could be improved then they should absolutely create a new answer based on the old one. **If** they explicitly acknowledge that they are building on the old answer and give credit, then there is no plagiarism and everybody benefits from a new, better answer.

Also, if the ability of copying a snippet into a new answer were removed, the removal would be trivially overcome by using cut-and-paste. So plagiarists would still be able to plagiarize.

If this capability is in fact causing a spike in plagiarism, then perhaps there's a problem to be addressed. However, I'm with Servy on this: I'd want to see evidence of the spike before I support a change.